# Google AppInvite

Tags: java, android, google-app-invites

Realize `Google AppInvite` by `Google` manual - [link](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app?configured=true#sending-invitations).

Start Invite `Activity` and get next in the LogCat:

```
E/AppInviteAgent: Get suggested invitees failed due to error code: 3
            No Android client ID is found for package name <MY_PACKAGE_NAME>. (APPINVITE_CLIENT_ID_ERROR)

E/AppInviteAgent: Create invitations failed due to error code: 3
            No Android client ID is found for package name <MY_PACKAGE_NAME>. (APPINVITE_CLIENT_ID_ERROR)
```

Then I add a Log.d in the `onActivityResult` method and get in the LogCat:

```
onActivityResult: requestCode=0, resultCode=3
```

Can somebody help me ? I try to fix it about 2 weeks.

**UPD0**

```
// my `build.gradle` file (project level)
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
// my `build.gradle` file (app level)

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
// ... some code
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0'
     // for in-app-billing v3
     compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.31'
}
// and in the end of the file
// for Google Invite
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

// my methods in the MainActivity
private void onInviteClicked() {
        Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(
                getString(R.string.txt_invitation_title))
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.txt_invitation_message))
                .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.txt_invitation_cta))
                .build();
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
}
// where REQUEST_INVITE - private static final int and equal 0;

// and onActivityResult - copy from `Google` manual
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    new MyLogs("onActivityResult: requestCode=" + requestCode + ", resultCode=" + resultCode);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_INVITE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Check how many invitations were sent and log a message
            // The ids array contains the unique invitation ids for each invitation sent
            // (one for each contact select by the user). You can use these for analytics
            // as the ID will be consistent on the sending and receiving devices.
            String[] ids = AppInviteInvitation.getInvitationIds(resultCode, data);
            new MyLogs(getString(R.string.sent_invitations_fmt, ids.length));
        } else {
            // Sending failed or it was canceled, show failure message to the user
            new MyLogs("send_failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information, e.g. what you want to achieve, some source code etc.

Comment: @manniL, check update0.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the json configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

In firebase console under Project Settings find "Certificate Fingerprints (SHA-1)" part and from the help icon you will be directed to https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth and enter generated SHA1 keys for both release and debug certificate fingerprints. Then resultCode 3 will gone and you will send the invitation.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to generate your APK in release mode, not debug mode.

Comment: I have an application in Google Play and appinvite doesn't work there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you double-checked your **OAuth Client ID** of your project in [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/)?

Make sure you correctly put your project's **SHA-1** and **package name**. I suggests you created **two** client IDs: one with SHA-1 for `debug` key, and another for `release` key.

You can also safely remove `google-services.json` file and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` code in your app-level `build.gradle` file since *"it is just a quickstart helper to generate some basic android-resource files for easier integration of specific Google API features."* as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33083898/3273872).

Comment: Yes, I have an OAuth Client ID in my Google Developer Console. Okey, if I will delete a `*.json` file and `apply plugin: ..." my app invite will be started when I launch my app on real device with signing ? I don't want to make a new release for test appinvite.

Comment: The error said `...  No Android client ID is found for package name ...`, are you sure you have entered _correct_ **package name** in your project's OAuth Client ID? Yes it will work just fine, I have tested it on my J5 on debug version and Alpha APK on Google Play Developer Console.

Comment: Are you also sure it's your `OAuth Client ID`, **not** `API Key` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36118171/3273872)?

Comment: Yes, because the name is "Android client for <MY_PACKAGE_NAME> (auto created by Google Service)"

Comment: simplebe, I was delete a OAuth and create new. But it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it should work automatically, if you have connected your Firebase with your app on Google Play, but you have to download your application from Google Play. I had the same problem and it didn't work in my case, because I had the version of an application which I installed straight from the computer (debug mode).